# How to display value of row and column for html table

Tags: javascript

I created Html table using JavaScript. Its working perfectly, its giving me row and column perfectly. But I want to display the cell value

Javscript Code

```
   var table ="";
var row = 2;
var cols = 2;
//var row =2,cols =4;
for(var r=0; r<row;r++)
    {
        table+='<tr>';  // open row
        for (var c=1; c<=cols;c++)
            {
                table += "<td>"+ c+'</td>';
            }
        table+= "</tr>"; // close row
    }
document.write("<table>"+ table + "</table>");
```

output

```
1 2
1 2
```

Wanted output. cell 2,1 would have "(2,1)" in it

```
1,1  2,1
1,2  2,2
```

What am I missing ? I try to give the for loop value but no success.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table += <td>" + r + "," + c +'</td>`

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was missing something silly. Thank you

Comment: I will do that, but I have to wait for atleast 10 minute to do so

Comment: It doesn't give the correct output though. It gives `0,1 0,2 1,1 1,2`

Comment: Because your loop to create the rows starts with zero instead of one.

Comment: Well, You can use table += <td>" + (r + 1) + "," + c +'</td>

Comment: To get what OP wants you need `c +"," + (r+1)`